# How to get machine accuracy agreement between Fortran 77 and Java numerical codes?

Tags: java, fortran, ieee-754, fortran77

I have a numerical code in Fortran77 (gfortran). I translated it to Java (jdk7).

I would like to have exactly the same results for these two codes with machine accuracy. Is there a way to achieve that? Are there any compiler switches which would enforce gfortran and jdk7 to operate on floating point numbers in exactly the same way?

The problem is that the code is very complex and after some time the two codes start to give a little bit different results (because of the rounding of floating point numbers I think). Statistically the results look the same but I really, really would like to be able to compare them with the machine accuracy.

Comment: Java has a keyword strictfp, which enforces the calculations to be performed in the same way on all machines, try to declare your class as strictfp, but it could' not work as in fortran 77

Comment: The keyword strictfp can help within Java. However, I still need to compare it to Fortran.

Comment: @ahypki, I just tried using `strictfp` with some of my older Java programs and compared the output to that produced by the Fortran versions...not stellar agreement as I was hoping.

Answer (score 3):

This will be almost impossible, especially for complex codes. Try disabling optimizations. Be sure to use the same size of floating point variables in both versions (doubles). You must be sure you did not change any expression, you have the same parentheses in both versions, same order of multiplications and additions...

Use `-fprotect-parens`, `-fno-unsafe-math-optimizations`, `-frounding-math` in gfortran and something similar for Java.

Track where exactly the difference emerges and examine how those lines differ in Fortran and in Java.

Comment: All optimizations are off. 

I use the same types in Fortan and in Java (float, double etc.) - the code is translated one-to-one. 

All instructions are as close as possible to each other. All expressions are the same. 

The multiplications and divisions are in the same order. I am able to precisely track the first changes between the codes but they start to differ in the 15th place after 'dot' (e-15 difference) and then the change propagates. 

Anyway, I will try the compiler options suggested by you. Thanks.

Comment: There is no magic switch to solve everythig for you, print intermediate results and find out on which line the difference first happens.